# How put data in coloumn which data get from one row in sqlite and put to string/textview

Tags: android

How to put data one row from sqlite to textview. I have 2 textview and I want to get data from database sqlite. This is my query:

```
public Cursor getItem(long itemId) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT name, link FROM tes WHERE "
            + BaseColumns._ID + "=" + itemId;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    return cursor;
}
```

And how to put contents of name and link to textview. I want to put in below:

```
String name = ""; // how to get contents of name from coloumn name in my query?
String link = ""; // how to get contents of link from coloumn link in my query?

textName.setText(name);
textLink.setText(link);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();

if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
String name = cursor .getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")).trim();
String link  = cursor .getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("link ")).trim();

textName.setText(name);
textLink.setText(link);

}
cursor.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Cursor c1 =getItem(long itemId);
c1.moveToFirst();

if(c.getCount()>0){
        String name = c1.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"));; 
        String link = c1.getString(c.getColumnIndex("link")); 

        textName.setText(name);
        textLink.setText(link);
}
```